# nodejs code analysis tool for specific version

Tags: node.js, analytics

We have a project built with NodeJS. With time the version upgrades are very necessary but while updating the version, if we do not have enough test cases, something might break and we may know it far later. Such a scenario was introduced when `replaceAll` method was used in some part of the code. But `replaceAll` is not supported until NodeJS 15 or later. So we run into trouble after merging the code.

Can we check whether the NodeJS code works or not for a specific version?

Demonstration:
I've created a repository on GitHub for this with a workflow to demonstrate the problem. See this run https://github.com/kiranparajuli589/node-check/runs/7573211393?check_suite_focus=true

Here I've used Node 14 and properly configured the `engines` keyword in the package.json but still, the linter is not reporting about the usages of such functions that are not available.

Comment: Linting should identify undefined methods if the engines are configured correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this with ESlint, and it did not work. It does not report if such functions are inside the code.

Comment: See the demonstration at here https://github.com/kiranparajuli589/node-check/runs/7573211393?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: You mean where the ESLimt cpnfig doesn’t have engines set, an env of 2021, and ecmaversion set to latest?

Comment: True :) I have these latest values in the eslintrc. How can I configure engines in eslintrc? How should I choose ecmaversion w.r.t. nodejs version?